# Метод Монте-Карло для нетривиальных интегралов

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Объясните, пожалуйста, как применять метод Монте-Карло для двойного интеграла с бесконечными пределами интегрирования. Как делать для определенного понятно [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_Монте-Карло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE). Но как сделать для двойного?

P.S.: решать не нужно, просто подскажите алгоритм, пожалуйста

Comment: Вас смущает именно двойной интеграл, или именно бесконечные пределы интегрирования?

Comment: @Harry и то, и то)

Comment: Ну, для двумерной области - как и для одномерной - только и того, что точки оказываются в трехмерном пространстве. С бесконечными пределами сложнее - как варианты, оценивать хвосты по асимптотике и отрезать, или искать преобразование, которое бы свело интеграл к ограниченной области, но без бесконечных значений самой подынтегральной функции (не уверен, что такое отыщется в общем случае), или как-то потом убирать сингулярности...

Comment: сомневаюсь, что методом МК можно вычислить этот интеграл с бесконечными пределами эффективно.

Comment: Harry прав. нужно заменой переменных перейти от интеграла с бесконечными пределами к интегралам с конечными пределами

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Я как-то в далекой студенческой молодости хотел посчитать на калькуляторе (ну не было тогда персоналок :), а МК-61 уже были) такой интеграл - Симпсоном, конечно, а не Монте-Карло - преобразовав в конечные пределы. Но добиться преобразования такого, чтоб подынтегральная функция не уходила в бесконечность, мне тогда не удалось. Больше я к этому не возвращался (просчитал с переменным шагом), но теперь интересно - а существует ли такое преобразование вообще? которое приводит такой "бесконечный" интеграл к красивому конечному виду? Хотя бы в каких-то частных случаях?

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, можно преобразовать, если интеграл сходится.  
 подинтегральную функцию преобразовывают еще

Answer (score 2):

Не более чем иллюстрации для - применение метода Монте-Карло к вычислению объема шара единичного радиуса (двойной интеграл по области x^2+y^2 <= 1 функции 2*sqrt(1-x^2-y^2)).

Для наглядности она из полученного значения вычисляет число "пи".

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    default_random_engine e;
    uniform_real_distribution r(-1.0,1.0);


    unsigned long long total = 0, vol = 0;
    for(unsigned long long i = 1; ; ++i)
    {
        double x = r(e), y = r(e), z = r(e);
        ++total;
        if (x*x+y*y > 1.0) continue; // Выход за область интегрирования

        if (z*z < 1 - x*x - y*y) ++vol;  // Точка входит в область

        if (i%1000000 == 0)
            cout << 6.0*vol/total << endl;
    }

}
```

Запускайте и смотрите сами :)